# Android loses Network connection and it stays disconnected

Tags: android, networking

Im am working on a App that has to work in the Background, and it has to send Geolocation. It is allready in production and we sometimes have the problem that an App just stoppes sending information.

It seems that only a restart of the Phone helps.

Now I have to fix this somehow, it seems to me that resetting the Networkstack would solve the problem. My question is this, how can I programticlly reset the network connection? Or does anybody have any other suggestions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I programticlly reset the network connection? Or does anybody
>   have any other suggestions for this problem.

You should not go for start a network connection programatically. I would suggest you to check for network connection before posting the location to server, and if device is disconnected show the notification to user to enable network connection.

*Why I am not in favor of set network connection by code*

This functionality can cost the user. So raise a notification and let the user to start network connection.

And yes if user dosn't start the network connection your application will not post location any more.

---

***Update for Listen device network state***

Register a Receiver to listen for [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

For example:

```
BroadcastReceiver sampleNetworkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w("sampleNetworkStateReceiver", "Network State has Changed");
    //For a disconnect event, the boolean extra EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY is set to true if there are no connected networks at all.
        // So you need to get EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY extra from intent.
        // that will tell you if device has loses the conectivity.  

        boolean noConnectivity =
            intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

        if (noConnectivity) {
            //TODO: Task for Device has no connection
        } else {
            //TODO: Task for Device has connection
        }
    }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
registerReceiver(sampleNetworkStateReceiver, filter);
```

Ref : [NetworkConnectivityListener](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java) and [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Comment: The problem is this. How do I know if the Internet Connection is gone because there is simply no Network Connection Available, in witch case the right thing to do is just to wait until the User is back in range and the case when the Phones Network Stack crashed?